# Nginx change request header value conditionally

Tags: if-statement, nginx, http-headers, nginx-reverse-proxy

How to change request header value conditionally depending on another header value in nginx reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nginx [ngx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html). 
A good example is here - [Mapping Headers in Nginx](https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-mapping-headers).

Basically you need to map the requested header (I used the from_header in the configuration below)to the new header (to_header in the example) and later use [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header).

```
map $http_from_header $to_header {
    default a;
    value_1 b;
    value_2 c;
}

server {
....

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header To_Header $to_header;
   }
}
```

Nginx takes any HTTP headers, lower-cases them, and converts dashes to underscores. They become accessible as variables starting with $http_.

That way you should get what you need.

Good luck